# Tasks environment: How to set counter to begin at number other than #1

Tags: enumitem, tasks

In the mwe below, I want the question number counter to start at #44 instead of #1 because this doc is part 2 of a larger problem set:

I tried inserting `\task\SetTaskNumber{44}` but that produced an `undefined control sequence error`.

Being a tex newby, I don't really understand how and where the enumeration is created. Guessing the executing code line is `\begin{tasks} [style=enumerate](2)`.

If possible, please identify the code line that specifies a starting number of "1" and how to change that starting number to "44".

Thanks very much for taking time to read and respond to this!

mwe:

````
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.5in,include head]{geometry}
\printanswers
% un-comment to print solutions.
\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[nice]{nicefrac}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{arr/.style = {blue,-{Triangle[angle=60:1pt 3]}, thick,
            shorten <=2mm, shorten >=2mm}
          } 
\newcommand\arr{\tikz[baseline=-0.65ex]           % <--- new
\draw[blue,-{Triangle[angle=60:1pt 3]}, very thick, 
      shorten <=2mm, shorten >=2mm   
      ] (0,0) -- ++ (1,0);             }
\pagestyle{head}
\header{\textbf{ Algebra II: Q4 Final Exam: R E V I E W (Units 12-15)}}
{}
{} 
\newcommand{\pagetop}{%
 }
\newlength{\lwidth}
\settowidth{\lwidth}{(99)\enspace} 
\settasks{after-item-skip=1em,
    after-skip=2cm,
    label-width=\lwidth,
    item-indent=0pt,   
    label=(\arabic*), % 
    label-offset = -\lwidth,
    item-format = \hspace{\lwidth},
    column-sep=2em,    
}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\fullwidth}[1]{%
    \vbox{%     
        \leftskip=-\lwidth \rightskip=0pt
        \advance\linewidth\@totalleftmargin%
        \@totalleftmargin=0pt%
        #1}%
    \nobreak
}

\begin{document}
%definition for bigskip = 1 line to replace all \bigskip
\def\bigskip{\vskip\bigskipamount}
\begin{tasks}
[style=enumerate](2)
 % undefined control sequence error: ***\task\SetTaskNumber{44}***
\task![]\fullwidth{\textbf
{Simplify each radical expression.}}
%%% Prob #1
\task 
$5\sqrt48$
\begin{solutionorbox}[\SolutionSpace]
$5\sqrt{48}\arr 5(\sqrt{16})(\sqrt3) \arr (5)(4)(\sqrt3)$\bigskip
\colorbox{yellow}{$20\sqrt3$}
\end{solutionorbox}

%%%%%%%%Prob #2
\task
$\sqrt{16x^{14}}$
\begin{solutionorbox}[\SolutionSpace]
$(\sqrt{16})(\sqrt{x^{14}}) \arr 4(x^{14\div 2})$\bigskip
\colorbox{yellow}{$4x^7$}
\end{solutionorbox}
\end{tasks}
\end{document}```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the `start=...` key for the task specification:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{tasks}
\begin{document}
\begin{tasks}
    [style=enumerate,start=44](2)
    \task A question
    \task Another one
\end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: sooo very simple. Thanks so much for the assist!